# Is "The Blazing World" written in a standard style for Cavendish's time?

Tags: history-of-literature, style, margaret-cavendish, the-blazing-world

I've been assigned [*The Blazing World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blazing_World) by Margaret Cavendish to read in my literature class. The first thing that struck me about the writing is how *long* the sentences are. It takes a mental settling-in to get in the right headspace for understanding the clauses. Opening to a random page:

> The Empress being thus persuaded by the Duchess to make an imaginary world of her own, followed her advice; and after she had quite finished it, and framed all kinds of creature proper and useful for it, strengthened it with good laws, and beautified it with arts and sciences; having nothing else to do, unless she did dissolve her imaginary world, or made some alterations in the Blazing World she lived in, which yet she could hardly do, by reason it was so well ordered that it could not be mended; for it was governed without secret and deceiving policy; neither was there any ambition, factions, malicious detractions, civil dissensions, or home-bred quarrels, divisions in religion, foreign wars, etc. but all the people lived in a peaceful society, united tranquility, and religious conformity; she was desirous to see the world the Duchess came from, and observe therein the several sovereign governments, laws, and customs of several nations.
> <sub>*The Blazing World and Other Writings* (Penguin Classics), page 189</sub>

That is a *single sentence*, with a *single full-stop* (not counting the `.` in "etc."). Granted, there are many semicolons, but that's also more semicolons in a row, without full stops, than I'm used to seeing. Flipping (again randomly) finds another example, this one with only a single semicolon but still a considerable number of commas:

> But they told her Majesty, that Fortune was so inconstant, that although she would perhaps promise to hear their cause pleaded, yet it was a thousand to one, but she would never have the patience to do it: nevertheless, upon her Majesty's request, they tried their utmost, and at last prevailed with Fortune so far, that she chose Folly, and Rashness, for her friends, but they could not agree in choosing a judge; until at last, with much ado, they concluded, that Truth should hear, and decide the cause.
> <sub>page 196</sub>

Checking [some](https://digital.library.upenn.edu/women/newcastle/blazing/blazing.html) online [versions](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/51783/pg51783-images.html) shows a similar habit. I'm interested in whether this was simply the accepted writing style for the time, or if it was a quirk of Cavendish in particular. However, I'm not quite sure how to look for this. Obviously it wouldn't make sense to compare with other categories of works - plays, poems, etc. have their own conventions - but I'm not sure what other works would be considered contemporaries. Looking at [Wikipedia's list of 17th century works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/17th_century_in_literature), I clicked on a 1667 text [*Grace Abounding to the Chief of Sinners*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Abounding_to_the_Chief_of_Sinners), whose [Project Gutenberg copy](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/654/pg654-images.html) has shorter sentences. But that's only one datapoint and I'm not sure it's a valid one: see previous doubts over what would be good comparisons.

Are these long, many-claused sentences an artifact of the time Cavendish was writing in, or are they more personal to her?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3602/is-there-a-historical-trend-towards-shorter-sentences

Comment: I think you're confusing grammatical sentence with typology. There's only one period, yes, but each section the semi-colons divide would be considered complete sentences with a period in modern typography.

Comment: @cmw Replacing semicolons with periods works for some of the semicolons in these examples, but others do not represent a break between two independent sentences. Personally, I would replace some of them with commas and some with em dashes. It would require some rewording to split these long sentences up into sentences of a "reasonable" length by today's standards.

Comment: "Each" might have been an overreach, but essentially yes, the grammar is far less complicated than on first glance.

Comment: It's one sentence as written — removing all the interior diversions, you get: "after she had quite finished it ... she was desirous to see the world the Duchess came from.

Comment: Relevant: [on long sentences by Mark Twain](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1780/17).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: The length of Cavendish’s sentences is unremarkable for the seventeenth century.

I found several modern studies of variation in sentence length across time, but none that covered the relevant span of time, or which examined specifically works of literary prose. So this answer is based on data from Edwin Herbert Lewis. In his [*History of the English Paragraph*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026640247) (1894), Lewis sampled (typically) 100–200 paragraphs from about seventy works of literary prose from the fifteenth to nineteenth centuries, and computed the average sentence length for each. I did the same for *The Blazing World*, getting an average sentence length of 50.82 words.

[image: Plot of year of work against average words per sentence, using the examples from Edwin Herbert Lewis.]

The plot shows that not everyone in this corpus wrote longer sentences in the seventeenth century (for example Fuller’s *Worthies of England* (1662) has an average sentence length of 23.45), but rather, that there was a greater variation in average length in this period than in later centuries, with a few works having more than 70 words per sentence. *The Blazing World* is in the middle of the pack for the seventeenth century portion of Lewis’s corpus.

Lewis attributed the lengthy sentences common in the seventeenth century to

> the Latin influence, which was rather towards disregarding paragraph mark or indentation as a sign of anything but emphasis [… and so] for a time we have the single-sentence paragraph of great length. The Latinists still think themselves bound to group many clauses in one sentence, but they feel the natural genius of the [English] language conflicting with their wish. They cannot discard their large unit of thought—that would be, to them, philosophic retrogression. They cannot—in the uninflected language—go on indefinitely prolonging the period. They determine to make long sentences still, and, when the periodic structure fails, to secure distinction and intelligibility for the long unit by paragraphing it. Hence arises the interminable paragraphed sentence, not strictly periodic, by any means, but articulated by all the points of the *periodos*—(: ; , .)
>
> <sub>Edwin Herbert Lewis (1894). [*History of the English Paragraph*, p. 44](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026640247/page/n51/mode/2up). University of Chicago Press.</sub>

The data in the plot comes from a table in [Lewis, pp. 35–36](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026640247/page/n41/mode/2up), which I have transcribed below, with a few minor corrections, and an approximate year for each work.

| Year | Author | Title | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1449 | Reginald Pecock | *The Repressor of Over Much Blaming of the Clergy* | 61.00 |
| 1528 | William Tyndale | *The Obedience of a Christian Man* | 31.72 |
| 1545 | Roger Ascham | *Toxophilus* | 43.13 |
| 1555 | Hugh Latimer | *Sermons* | 20.45 |
| 1565 | John Stow | *Summarie of Englyshe Chronicles* | 57.00 |
| 1578 | John Lyly | *Euphues* | 36.83 |
| 1579 | Philip Sidney | *The Defense of Poesie* | 38.80 |
| 1579 | Stephen Gosson | *School of Abuse* | 60.00 |
| 1580 | Thomas Cranmer | *Answer to Stephen Gardiner* | 37.22 |
| 1585 | Richard Hooker | *Of the Laws of Ecclesiastical Polity* | 41.23 |
| 1586 | William Webbe | *Discourse of English Poetrie* | 50.50 |
| 1605 | Francis Bacon | *The Advancement of Learning* | 60.03 |
| 1628 | Robert Burton | *Anatomy of Melancholy* | 40.14 |
| 1643 | Edward Herbert | *Autobiography* | 75.60 |
| 1644 | John Milton | *Areopagitica* | 50.70 |
| 1646 | Jeremy Taylor | *A Discourse of the Liberty of Prophesying* | 52.93 |
| 1651 | Thomas Hobbes | *Leviathan* | 39.26 |
| 1652 | Fulke Greville | *Life of Sidney* | 55.00 |
| 1658 | Thomas Browne | *Hydriotaphia, or Urn Burial* | 33.09 |
| 1660 | John Dryden | *Prefaces, Biographical and Critical, to the Works of the English Poets* | 38.44 |
| 1662 | Thomas Fuller | *Worthies of England* | 23.45 |
| 1665 | Izaak Walton | *The Life of Hooker* | 64.00 |
| **1666** | **Margaret Cavendish** | ***The Blazing World*** | **50.82** |
| 1668 | Abraham Cowley | *Essays* | 48.37 |
| 1678 | John Bunyan | *The Pilgrim’s Progress* | 31.61 |
| 1689 | John Selden | *Table Talk* | 33.58 |
| 1690 | William Temple | *On Heroic Virtue* | 53.40 |
| 1697 | Daniel Defoe | *An Essay Upon Projects* | 49.64 |
| 1702 | Edward Hyde | *The History of the Rebellion* | 74.94 |
| 1704 | Jonathan Swift | *A Tale of a Tub* | 40.74 |
| 1706 | John Locke | *Of the Conduct of the Understanding* | 49.80 |
| 1715 | Joseph Addison | *The Freeholder* | 38.58 |
| 1717 | Henry St John | *Letter to William Wyndham* | 34.86 |
| 1719 | Daniel Defoe | *Robinson Crusoe* | 78.68 |
| 1726 | Jonathan Swift | *Gulliver’s Travels* | 40.00 |
| 1727 | Jonathan Swift | *A Short View of the State of Ireland* | 49.80 |
| 1749 | Henry Fielding | *The History of Tom Jones, a Foundling* | 41.92 |
| 1759 | Samuel Johnson | *The History of Rasselas, Prince of Abissinia* | 38.15 |
| 1762 | David Hume | *The History of England* | 39.81 |
| 1766 | Oliver Goldsmith | *The Vicar of Wakefield* | 26.94 |
| 1768 | Laurence Sterne | *A Sentimental Journey Through France and Italy* | 36.50 |
| 1774 | Edmund Burke | *Speech on Moving Resolutions on Conciliation with America* | 26.09 |
| 1776 | Edward Gibbon | *The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire* | 31.21 |
| 1785 | William Paley | *The Principles of Moral and Political Philosophy* | 37.68 |
| 1809 | Samuel Coleridge | *The Friend* | 37.60 |
| 1819 | Walter Scott | *Ivanhoe* | 32.14 |
| 1820 | Washington Irving | *The Sketch Book of Geoffrey Crayon, Gent* | 26.73 |
| 1821 | Thomas De Quincey | *Confessions of an English Opium-Eater* | 38.81 |
| 1823 | Charles Lamb | *Essays of Elia* | 27.19 |
| 1827 | Thomas Carlyle | *Jean Paul Friedrich Richter* | 31.56 |
| 1829 | Walter Landor | *Imaginary Conversations* | 25.43 |
| 1833 | Thomas Carlyle | *Sartor Resartus* | 35.05 |
| 1837 | Thomas Carlyle | *The French Revolution: a History* | 23.89 |
| 1838 | William Channing | *Self-Culture* | 25.35 |
| 1841 | Charles Dickens | *The Old Curiosity Shop* | 23.78 |
| 1841 | Emerson | *Essays and Addresses* | 20.58 |
| 1843 | Thomas Macaulay | *Critical and Historical Essays* | 23.05 |
| 1844 | Francis Jeffrey | *Contributions to the Edinburgh Review* | 50.65 |
| 1848 | Thomas Macaulay | *The History of England from the Accession of James the Second* | 23.43 |
| 1850 | Charles Kingsley | *Alton Locke* | 23.74 |
| 1852 | Herbert Spencer | *The Philosophy of Style* | 30.38 |
| 1852 | John Newman | *The Idea of a University Defined and Illustrated* | 41.44 |
| 1865 | John Ruskin | *Sesame and Lilies* | 33.31 |
| 1865 | Matthew Arnold | *Essays in Criticism* | 34.41 |
| 1866 | James Lowell | *Carlyle* | 31.45 |
| 1874 | John Green | *A Short History of the English People* | 29.04 |
| 1876 | George Eliot | *Daniel Deronda* | 22.39 |
| 1889 | Walter Pater | *An Essay on Style* | 38.54 |
| 1893 | Barrett Wendell | *English Composition* | 25.65 |

(A caution for anyone trying to reproduce Lewis’s data: you need to make sure you have an original edition, as later editions may have edited the text to suit modern conventions. For example, the [1719 edition of *Robinson Crusoe*](https://archive.org/details/lifestrangesurpr01defo/page/n9/mode/2up) starts with a 106-word sentence, but in [this Project Gutenberg edition](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/521/pg521-images.html) it has been split into two sentences of 33 and 72 words, and in [this 1801 edition](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/11866/pg11866-images.html) it has been split into three sentences of 13, 20 and 44 words.)